# WPF LinearGradientBrush increase gap between lines

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I'm currently working on a .NET 4.7.1 application. I need to draw Rectangle Elements on a Canvas Element. The Rectangles should have a striped background (red/gray). To achieve this striped background I'm using the `LinearGradientBrush`.

So far it works quite good, I can achieve the striped background lines.

Unfortunately I don't know how to

- increase the gap between the lines
- make the lines thicker

My current coding looks like this:

```
<Canvas Background="gray">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Fill">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="red"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="red"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="gray"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="gray"/>
                        <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.01" ScaleY="0.01"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <Rectangle Panel.ZIndex="3" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="100" Width="200" Height="50"/>
</Canvas>
```

Do you know, how to achieve a background with striped lines and how to increase the gap between the lines as well as the thickness of one stripe, on a rectangle in a canvas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As already said, use a DrawingBrush. Where is the problem?

Comment: true, DrawingBrush works as a charm! got it now, Thank you!